# Installing PS3 Games Straight From Disc To external Hard Drive

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

Hello Everyone i was wondering if i could install grand theft auto from my disc to an expansion drive connected to the ps3. Any Help or Pointers Would help, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know no PlayStation 3 games support this. Some games will have either mandatory or optional install to the internal drive, but not to any sort of external storage. I believe both Grand Theft Auto IV and Grand Theft Auto V have mandatory installs, and would've installed themselves to the internal drive when you first ran the game. There's nothing you can do to move this install to an external hard drive.

If you have one of the newer 12 GB super slim PS3s you'll need to [install a hard drive inside the console](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5006/~/install-hard-disk-drive-%2812gb-ps3-%2F-cech-4201a%29) to get more space.